# MySQL and performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-update

I am effecting 50,000+ updates on a MySQPL table fairly frequently.  I tried it this way:

```
UPDATE data SET p=p+(13) where c=2 and g=12
UPDATE data SET p=p+(17) where c=3 and g=41
UPDATE data SET p=p+(-12) where c=6 and g=19
UPDATE data SET p=p+(-4) where c=8 and g=12
...
```

As you might imagine, it takes a while.  I measure it at about 45 sec.
So, I tried creating a temp table so I could get the same work done in less queries.  That looks like this:

```
CRATE TEMPORARY TABLE changes(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    g INT,
    c INT,
    delta_p INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
INSERT INTO changes(g,c,delta_p) VALUES (12,2,13),(41,3,17),(19,6,-12),(12,8,-4)...
UPDATE p INNER JOIN changes AS c ON p.c=c.c AND p.g=c.g SET p.p=p.p+c.delta_p
DROP TABLE changes
```

I liked this solution at first because I was under the assumption that less queries would almost always be faster.  I thought cutting down from 50,000 queries to 4 would make a difference.  What I observe, however, is that it is about 10x slower.  I measured the second method at 500 sec.

I really want to know how to speed this up, but my question here is: Why is the second method so much slower? Can anyone give me some insight into why I'm seeing this behavior?

Comment: did you put indexes onto the fields in your temp table? general rule of thumb: ANY field used in a `where` clause or other "decision making" capacity SHOULD have an index on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index on the `changes` table:

```
create index changes_c_g on changes(c, g);
```

This will speed up the `join` a lot.  A covering index would help even more:

```
create index changes_c_g_deltap on changes(c, g, delta_p);
```

Comment: @zerkms, You say it's not `changes` that is slow? Does that mean I could expect to see a speedup if I indexed `c`,`g`, and `p` in table `p`?

Comment: @Luke: no it doesn't. Your `UPDATE` query in the second case doesn't look right btw.

Comment: @zerkms What doesn't look right about it?  I tested it superficially, and I observed the desired behavior.

Comment: @Luke: what is table `p`?

Comment: @zerkms `create table p (id int auto_increment, c int, g int, p int, primary key(id))`

Comment: I did a quick test with adding index on the three columns in `changes` and it seems to be about 5 times faster than submitting the updates individually.

Comment: @Luke . . . So, if my arithmetic is correct, it finishes in about 9 seconds.  It is 98% faster than the original form of the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure where your arithmetic comes from. 9/45 = .2 = 20%: it takes 20% of the time it did before.  So, the execution time decreased by 80%. Thanks for your answer, by the way.